# Android - Align options menu to the left side and change its default icon

Tags: java, android

When I included following code in my Activity file, I got the options menu on the right side with three vertical dots:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            //code
        }
    }
```

I need to do following things:

1. Shift the options menu to the left side
2. Show 3 horizontal lines instead of 3 dots for options menu

In short, I need options menu like PAYTM app.

http://images.indianexpress.com/2016/12/paytm_big_new.jpg

What is the way to shift the options menu to left and change its appearance?

Comment: you at least always can create the menu manually using `PopupWindow`

Comment: @VladMatvienko - Yes we can do, but is there no way to do it with options menu? I searched a lot but did not find any answer. Options menu is on the left side in many apps I have in my mobile phone.

Comment: are you sure that it's the options menu, and not the Navigation Drawer?

Comment: @VladMatvienko - No, I am not sure.

Comment: then it has to be the navigation drawer, and not the options menu.

Comment: @VladMatvienko - So, it means the functionality I am looking for cannot be achieved by options menu. I have to use Navigation Drawer for this. Right?

Comment: I think that if you spend few days investigating it, you might be able to do it with the options menu, but it would look ugly since options menu isn't designed for that, and the navigation drawer is.

Comment: @VladMatvienko - Thanks for your suggestion. I will now switch to Navigation Drawer. I was trying to achieve it with options menu. Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Navigation Drawer.
You can find how to implement it here: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: So, it means the functionality I am looking for cannot be achieved by options menu. I have to use Navigation Drawer for this. Right?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!